# COUNTIF in Tableau?

Tags: function, tableau-api, table-functions, level-of-detail

I have a simple COUNTIF task in Excel that is proving rather difficult to replicate in Tableau...

This is the data:

```
ID   Metric   Scope   DynamicCalc
1    A1       TRUE    X
1    B1       FALSE   X
2    B1       TRUE    X
2    A1       FALSE   X
2    C1       FALSE   X
```

The column 'DynamicCalc' should have the following values when `Metric=A1` is selected: `TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE` but if say `B1` is selected it would be `FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE`... so basically I want to assign a value of TRUE to the DynamicColumn if there is at least one TRUE in the Scope column to all rows for that ID.

Comment: could you explain better what you mean with "when Metric=A1 is selected"? do you mean filtered?

Comment: yes, I mean filtered

Comment: Do you have Tableau Version 9 ? or less than 9 ?

Comment: Tableau 9, so can use LODs... tried a few already, but couldn't figure that one out

Comment: Can you use 1 , 0 instead of TRUE and FALSE in `Scope` Field

Comment: Just realized I can't use LODs here as I need to bring the result into another formula to calculate the status and using LODs would hit the usual Tableau problem of "can't mix aggregate with non-aggregate..."

Comment: And yes, can use 1,0

Answer (score 0):

The `LOD` Expression can be used to retrieve your desired result 
try using a `calculated field` like below :

```
{FIXED [ID],[Metric]:MAX(if [Scope]='TRUE' then 'True' else 'False' end)}
```

When the Selection is B1 :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but as SO community (bot) has made it active again, I propose a slightly different approach.  The selection should be through parameter.

After making parameter on `Metric` field, create a calculated field say `Dynamic calc` like this

```
{FIXED ID : MAX({FIXED ID, [Metric]: MAX(If [Metric] = [Metric Parameter] THEN [Scope] END)})}
```

Add this field and your desired view is complete.  See GIF below

[image]